# What will happen with my devices after Google Cloud IoT Core get retired

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As announced by Google, the IoT Core will be retired on August 16, 2023.
I already have some ESP32 using Mongoose-OS and Google IoT Core to connect, send and receive telemetry.
What will happen after August 16? Will all the connected devices be disconnected and I need to use another technical approach (rework needed)?

Answer (score 0):

When Google Cloud IoT Core is retired, your existing devices will likely be unable to use the service. But note that Google has not provided specific information on what will happen to devices that were connected to IoT Core, so you may want to check with them or plan for alternative solutions before August 16.